# Проблемы с масштабированием Главного меню - Unity Canvas

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. В окне игры редактора Unity главное меню отображается с нормальными пропорциями, но при увеличении интерфейс не увеличивается вместе с окном (или увеличивается, но точно не так, как хотелось бы).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пишите дополнителюную информацию в комментариях, вместо этого редактируйте сам вопрос, а комментарий можно удалить.

Comment: На канвасе есть компонент `CanvasScaler`... название вобщем то говорящее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В параметрах `Canvas` есть `CanvasScale`. В нëм выбери `Scale with screen size`

Comment: спасибо огромное! вроде бы это было так очевидно, но очень мне помогло, ибо я убил на поиск ответа на вопрос много времени.

Comment: Да, у меня так же было, пока я случайно не нашëл это на просторах интернета)